# Arch does not detect modem switching via a mechanical switch

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, arch-linux, switch

Having two internet connections at home, I bought this switch to choose which network to use:
[image]

The problem is, like flipping the switch, the Arch doesn't notice the network change and hangs until I reset it with:

```
nmcli con down 'Network 1'
nmcli con up 'Network 1'
```

### How can I do to have the connection reset automatically?

### **Update:**

I bought this mechanical switch because I wanted an economical and low energy solution

I'm no expert, but any managed switch would be an overkill solution.

I ran the **ip monitor** command and then flipped the switch:

```
$ ip monitor
192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx STALE 
192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx PROBE 
192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 FAILED 
xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev enp3s0 lladdr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx router PROBE 
192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 FAILED 
xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev enp3s0 router FAILED 
192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 FAILED 
xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev enp3s0 router FAILED 
192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 FAILED 
xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev enp3s0 router FAILED 
192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 FAILED
```

### Update 2:

For clarity, I'm adding my home network infrastructure.
[image]

Comment: What about using a soft switch that your OS can switch. Make a batch file to switch both the connection and the network.  I have seen soft switches in my electronics travels.

Comment: It would probably reset automatically if there was a detectable moment of disconnection in between the two connections. If you push the button slowly or halfway, can you get it to a point where it's disconnected from both for a long moment, and then you can finish switching it? Physically unplugging and re-plugging the cables wouldn't have this problem, but might wear out the connectors eventually.

Comment: @John Can you give me an example of soft switches?

Comment: I was thinking of something like this:   https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/TS5A4595DBVR/716558?utm_adgroup=Texas%20Instruments&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax%20Shopping_Supplier_Texas%20Instruments&utm_term=&productid=716558&gclid=Cj0KCQjw6cKiBhD5ARIsAKXUdyYoDOuH6WtKUXR50miwatoPbY5GUE0fsJoY9DILgQiaXvVaFI1CyU8aAp0LEALw_wcB

Comment: Its probably a slightly more expensive solution, but I feel like a managed switch and vlans would be a more 'usual' way to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by running in the background this script in python which checks the connection every 20 seconds.

And if the check fails, it resets the connection.

```python
import os, time

def resetConn():
    os.system("nmcli con down 'Network 1'")
    os.system("nmcli con up 'Network 1'")
    
def testConn():
    l = ['192.168.2.1', '192.168.1.1'] # test ip my network
    c = 0
    for i in l:
        p = os.popen('ping -w 1 ' + i).read()
        if '0 received' in p:
            c +=1
    return len(l) == c
    
while True:
   if testConn():
        resetConn()
        print("Connection reset.\n")
   time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do to have the connection reset automatically?

First, watch `dmesg -ew` or `ip monitor` to *verify* that your mechanical switch always causes the Ethernet interface to see carrier loss, i.e. it needs to report `eth0: <NO-CARRIER>` at least for a moment. (I really *hope* that the mechanical switch is built so that it will always happen, otherwise it's kind of garbage, though of course you can train yourself to switch it slowly.)

But as you are using NetworkManager, there is an additional **5-second** soft delay until NM deconfigures an interface after carrier loss. (The assumption is that a physical unplug/replug will generally take longer than that.) If the carrier returns immediately, NM considers it to be just a glitch and retains the old configuration. To avoid this, set the `carrier-wait-timeout` parameter in NM's global configuration to zero milliseconds:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/carrier.conf
[device]
match-device=interface-name:en*
carrier-wait-timeout=0
```

But honestly, if this is a desktop machine, then get a second Ethernet port and do all the switching in software – bring eth0 down, bring eth1 up. (You probably have a spare PCI Express x1 slot for that.) In that setup, it would even become possible to set up ISP 1 for *some* traffic and ISP 2 for everything else, simultaneously.

(Alternatively, as suggested in comments, an Ethernet switch (in the usual sense of a "powered Ethernet splitter with blinky lights") with VLAN support would be a nice solution – you can have your PC's single Ethernet port receive both ISPs as tagged VLANs, e.g. `eth0.3` and `eth0.7`, again manually bringing one down and the other up, or using both simultaneously.)

Comment: The **/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/** folder is empty. just create the file for the changes to take effect? I've also updated the question.

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea of most `.d` folders (and in general, it's quite valid for a config file to not exist by default). You'd need to restart the NM service to apply changes. It probably won't help here though – according to the `ip monitor` output, which does not show any interface status changes (all it shows is neighbor cache changes), the switch most likely happens too fast for the Ethernet port to notice anything. Physically unplug the cable, note what "ip monitor" shows for it (`eth0: <NO-CARRIER>` or such), then try _slowly_ switching the buttons to get the same result.

Comment: I've updated my question. `ip monitor` displays `eth0:<NO-CARRIER>` if I physically unplug my computer from **switch 1**